# Ncurses windows, installed with mingw but unable to include in src codes

Tags: c, windows, mingw, ncurses

I tryied to install ncurses with the mingw installer but when i include the library on vscode with "#include <ncurses.h> or <curses.h>", it just says that it can't find any library.

Hi,
I'm doing a project for my IT programming class at university, i'm at the ending of the project and i want to make it feel easy to use to the users, for that i want to do some text based gui since the program has to run in terminal.
Well the programm is in C and the only reasonable and decent thing that i found online was ncurses, i mean i could use ANSI escape codes, but one requirement for it is that it has to run on windows/linux/mac, so ANSI escape codes just don't work on standard windows terminal, and i do not wan't the users having to install the newer terminal or to modify the current, so yea, ncurses i think that could be a solution (if someone has better idea i'm listening, but keep in mind that i already watch a course to ncurses so it has to be really better to make me change my mind).
Well, now come the real issue, in linux everythings fine, i installed ncurses package and i'm already ready to go, but to work on windows i'm using mingw, and i installed via the mingw installer the ncurses packages, now when i'm trying to include with vscode the library with "#include <ncurses.h> or <curses.h>" it says that it can't find the library, i searched in the whole folder of mingw where the f**k ncurses is but there just isn't.
Since the mingw installer says that ncurses is installed, i think that it has been installed somewhere, and now i just need to include in the system path,or something like that, am i right?
If someone have already experience with ncurses and mingw i would be really gratefull.

Comment: The header files might be in a subdirectory "ncurses" or "ncursesw" (for the narrow and wide character variants of ncurses) of mingw's standard include directory, so you need to add that directory to the `includePath` array in your VSCode project's "c_cpp_properties.json" file.

Comment: Under windows `vcpkg` and native compiler would make life easier. This way you can install thousands of packages with a single line command per package. Using also `cmake` in Linux and Windows could mean a single build script also... Anyway since Unix `curses` this is a great way to build windowing  terminal interfaces in C or C++. Which is your environment (IDE)?

Comment: Thanks! I'm currently using VSCode, I saw that there is an extension for vcpkg, i installed it, but how actually vcpkg works with the compiler? I mean if I install ncurses via vcpkg than if i run a 'gcc -lncurses example.c -o example.exe' would it works?

Comment: Add the `-I` compiler flag with the path where the `.h` file is you want to include, and the `-L` linker flag with the path containing the library file.